# How to use Grunt wiredep with RxJS

Tags: gruntjs, rxjs, grunt-wiredep, wiredep

RxJS lists several (35) variations of JavaScript distribution files.

`$ cat bower_components/rxjs/bower.json | jq '.main' | grep .js | wc -l`

when [wiredep](https://www.npmjs.org/package/wiredep) executes, all (35) file paths are injected into the target file, when I really only want one of the files.

How do I specify only one to be injected?

Answer (score 1):

use [wiredep's Bower Overrides](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#bower-overrides)

in *your* `bower.json` specify:

```
    ...
    "overrides": {
        "rxjs": {
            "main": "dist/rx.lite.compat.js"
        }
    }
    ...
```